# X509 certificate when communicating with the Google API's in .NET?

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, x509certificate2

I've been spending some time coding a Console Application in C# which communicates with the Google Analytics API's.

When I execute the code as a stand-alone console application, everything works fine. However, as soon as I try to integrate the code into a SharePoint (or other IIS-hosted software) as an ASP.NET type of solution, it doesn't work and it constantly fails on the loading of the certificate.

- Do we use SSL? **No.**
- Will we ever be using SSL? **Not in the nearest future, no.**
- Does the Console Application with the code below work? **Yes**
- Does the exact same code work in our web forms? **No**
- Have we tried loading the certificate-file (.p12) as a byte[] array as well? **Yes**

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        var serviceAccountEmail = "xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"CertFile-privatekey.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "GATest",
        });

        var r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:xxxxxx", "2014-01-01", "2014-02-01", "ga:pageviews");

        //Specify some addition query parameters
        r.Dimensions = "ga:source";
        r.Filters = "ga:pagePath=~/business/,ga:medium==referral";
        r.Segment = "gaid::-1";
        r.Sort = "-ga:pageviews";
        r.MaxResults = 50;

        //Execute and fetch the results of our query
        Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = r.Execute();
```

The rest of the logic isn't a vital part as it only handles rendering.

The line that breaks in the integrated (IIS-hosted) application is this one:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"CertFile-privatekey.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I guess the questions are summed up like this:

- Can we authenticate **without** the p12 file by specifying
  keys/passwords directly to the methods?
- Are there other options for authentication, or is this an SSL-issue?

As for actual error messages, Visual Studio just crashes and says that an exception was thrown. This happens on the X509Certificate2-line.

Thank you :-)

Comment: All OAuth 2.0 authentication options are available at - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth. As I understand you need to work with service account, right? Can you attach the exception (or VS crashes and you can't get it???)

Comment: In the end I got it working by creating a new WCF service which in turn is consuming the certificate and takes care of the GA communications. Then I am calling this WCF service from my other applications which allows me to decouple the logic from GA API's and my application endpoints and I only have to work with my custom WCF service instead.